# Probability that a random variable is zero as expressed as limit of a sequence

Tags: probability, sequences-and-series, limits, probability-distributions

Consider a random variable $U:\Omega \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ defined on the probability space $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, \mathbb{P})$. Suppose $U(\omega) \geq 0$ $\forall  \omega \in \Omega$. Consider a sequence of real numbers $\{\epsilon_n\}_n$ such that $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}\epsilon_n=0$. Does it make sense writing

$$ \mathbb{P}(U=0)=\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}\mathbb{P}(U <\epsilon_n)\tag{$*$}$$ or $(*)$ requires other assumptions? I'm confused on what should be behind $(*)$ and any hint would be really appreciated.

*I have found $(*)$ in van der Vaart "Asymptotic Statistics" p. 88

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\{U = 0\} = \bigcap_n \{-\varepsilon_n < U < \varepsilon_n\}$$

So

$$P(U=0) = \lim_{n \to \infty}P(-\varepsilon_n < U < \varepsilon_n)$$

But since $U \ge 0$, we have

$$P(U=0) = \lim_{n \to \infty}P(U < \varepsilon_n)$$